# Forecasting a tslm model with seasonal and cubic components

Tags: r

I'm having issues forecasting a model of the following form.

```
y1<-tslm(data_ts~ season+t+I(t^2)+I(t^3)+0)
```

It fits my data very well, but I run into a problem when attempting to do this:

```
forecast(y1,h=72)
```

This is the error that it gives me.

"Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 't')
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 72 rows but variables found have 1000 rows"

As far as I can tell, this has something do with using tslm and having the cubic function in it. If I just use "tslm(data_ds~season+trend)" everything works out fine, but I specifically need the model mentioned earlier. How can I forecast my model?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give and I apologize if this is a foolish question,

Johnson